# Window onload event misses sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am working on a page where I have to make interface changes on window.load. I am using

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
//all my code goes here
});
```

It works fine most of the time but very randomly few time, it doesn't execute at at all. I don't even get any error in the console. It is so random that I can't event reproduce this problem. My question is that is there anything more reliable than the window.onload event to make interface changes?

I also apologies in advance that I can't share the link.

Comment: You can try `jQuery(function() { ... });`, as suggested in https://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid jQuery and use plain javascript. You can use DOMContentLoad (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. Or addEventListener

```
window.addEventListener('load', callback)
```

Take a [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load).

Comment: This did not solve my problem exactly but it helped me find the actual issue.  Window load was triggering all the times. An element which I was using this event was not available on the first load and sometimes on random loads. That element was being loaded later via script.